# How exactly do or/and operators in Python behave?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, logical-operators

How exactly does Python evaluate statements connected by multiple and/or operators?

When I run the following statement in Python:

```
[1] or [] and (1,) or ()
```

the output is `[1]`.

But for the below statement,

```
[] or [1] and (1,) or ()
```

the output is `(1,)`.

I am confused. What causes the difference in outputs for both statements? What is the order of evaluation here?

Comment: You might want to read [_Truth Value Testing_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) from the documentation.

Comment: There are two separate pieces to this: understanding the order of operations, and understanding what each individual operation does (since the inputs are just not exactly `True` and `False`). Each of these has a well established duplicate, so I have linked them for you.

Comment: In short, a chain of ANDs will return the first false value, or the last true one; a chain of ORs will return the first true value, or the last false one; and AND has precedence over OR.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't evaluated strictly left-to-right: `and` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (binds more tightly) than `or`. So your examples are evaluated like so:

```
[1] or ([] and (1,)) or ()
```

`[1]` is "truthy", so the expression in parentheses isn't evaluated at all. `[1]` is the result of the first `or`. Similarly for the second `or`.

The other:

```
[] or ([1] and (1,)) or ()
```

`[]` is "falsey", so the expression in parentheses *is* evaluated. `[1]` is truthy, so `and` goes on evaluate `(1,)`, which is also truthy, and so is `and`'s result. Because `(1,)` is truthy, the second part of the second `or` isn't evaluated, and `(1,)` is the final result.

Note that "isn't evaluated" means what it says. For example,

```
>>> [] or [1] and (1,) or 1/0
(1,)
```

We didn't get a divide-by-zero exception because the `1/0` part is never evaluated - `or`'s left operand already determined the final outcome.

Comment: I get it now. I didn't know and has higher precedence than or. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

In **"or"** operator when one of the condition is true then it returns **"True"** if the both conditions are false it returns **"False"**

So with your first condition:
**"[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-logical-operators/) or [] and (1,) or ()"**

```
When you separate the conditions one-by-one as:
**[1] or []**
It returns true as one of the condition is true.

with second condition in this 
**[] and (1,)**
It will return false as one condition is true but it uses and operator.

with the third condition in this
**(1,) or ()**
It will return true as one of the condition is true.

If you put all the conditions together:
**"[1] or [] and (1,) or ()"**
We can expand it like 
**"T or F and T"**
It will return **"True"** as it satisfied the **or** operator.
```

In **"and"** operator it returns **"True"** when both the conditions are true if one of the conditions is false then it returns **"False"**

Same goes with your second condition
**[] or [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-logical-operators/) and (1,) or ()**

`Note: T for "True" F for "False"`

For reference you can go through [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-logical-operators/)

Answer (score -1):

[] and (1,): The and operator first evaluates [], which is considered False (an empty list). According to short-circuit evaluation, since the left operand is False, Python doesn't evaluate the right operand (1,). Instead, it returns [].

[1] or []: Since the left operand [1] is considered True (a non-empty list), Python short-circuits the or operator and returns [1].

So, overall, the expression [1] or [] and (1,) or () evaluates to [1].

```
print([1] or [] and (1,) or ())  # Output: [1]
```

However, in the other hand, the expression involves both and and or operators. To correctly evaluate this expression, we need to understand the precedence of these operators and how Python evaluates expressions involving them.

In Python, the and operator has higher precedence than the or operator. When multiple 'and' and 'or' operators are present in an expression, Python follows a ***left-to-right*** evaluation order.

Let's break down the expression step by step:

[1] and (1,): Since both [1] and (1,) are considered True (non-empty list and non-empty tuple respectively), the and operation returns the second operand, which is (1,).
[] or (1,): Since the left operand [] is considered False (empty list), Python evaluates the right operand (1,). The or operation returns the second operand, which is (1,).
(1,) or (): Both (1,) and () are considered True (non-empty tuple and non-empty tuple respectively). The or operation short-circuits and returns the first operand, which is (1,).
So, overall, the expression evaluates to (1,).

```
print([] or [1] and (1,) or ())  # Output: (1,)
```